# Why Regex matches odd charcters

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, lowercase

This regex:

```
((?<chrs>[a-z])\k<chrs>)+
```

Matches: "match"

From: "zzzzmatchzzzz" (4 z's each side)

But **why** when matching:

"zzzzzmatchzzzzz" (5 z's each side)

**Does it match the extra z's on each side as well?**

Comment: It [only matches 4 `z`s](https://regex101.com/r/DWNXil/1) on each side. What do you expect?

Comment: I wanted it to match all repeating chrs (z's) but I think my post should have solved it below.

Answer (score 0):

Played with Regex little more and found reason why:

```
((?<chrs>[a-z])\k<chrs>+)
```

the **+ should have been inside the end bracket** to say that it expects at least 1 match of 'chrs' and more rather than expects 1 match of 'chrs' as a match

Comment: Then why use named captures here? Just use `([a-z])\1+` - shorter and does the same.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that your pattern matches 1 or more *sequences* of a lowercase ASCII letter + identical lowercase ASCII letter, thus, it only matches pairs of identical adjoining lowercase ASCII letters.

- `(` - Starts a new group matching a sequence of

  - `(?<chrs>[a-z])` - a lowercase ASCII letter and places the value into Group "chrs"
  - `\k<chrs>` - and an identical char as matched in the "chrs" group
- `)+` - 1 or more times.

I would suggest a shorter `([a-z])\1+` regex to match sequences of 2 or more identical lowercase ASCII letters.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CrrVF3/1).